# How to create workflow to update SFDC multi-select picklist

Tags: workflow, formula-field, field-update

I need to create a workflow field update to update multiple values in a multi select picklist. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I dont' think there is a way to update multiselect picklist  using field update . You can try using trigger .

Answer (score 3):

You Can't do a "workflow field update" to update a MULTISELECT PICKLIST value. try another approach. You can try trigger logic.